# Devise does not let users update their info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

Before writing this I have checked out the [official guides](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password) and similar questions but somehow I keep getting problems and they don't help.

The thing is that I need the users to have the ability to change their passwords. To do that, I use Devise, and its views. I can use Devise perfectly in all other areas, but when I try this, even with account just created for that, It gives 2 errores: current password is not valid, and password confirmation is not valid.

I have tried sanitizers in two ways:

**users/registration_controller.rb**

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  # before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
  skip_before_action :require_no_authentication
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :authorize_admin!, only: :create
  # before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  # def new
  #   super
  # end

  # POST /resource
  def create
     build_resource(sign_up_params)

     resource.save
     yield resource if block_given?
     if resource.persisted?
       if resource.active_for_authentication?
         set_flash_message! :notice, :signed_up
         respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
       else
         set_flash_message! :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
         expire_data_after_sign_in!
         respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
       end
     else
       clean_up_passwords resource
       set_minimum_password_length
       respond_with resource
     end
  end

  # GET /resource/edit
  # def edit
  #   super
  # end

  # PUT /resource
  # def update
  #   super
  # end

  # DELETE /resource
  # def destroy
  #   super
  # end

  # GET /resource/cancel
  # Forces the session data which is usually expired after sign
  # in to be expired now. This is useful if the user wants to
  # cancel oauth signing in/up in the middle of the process,
  # removing all OAuth session data.
  # def cancel
  #   super
  # end

  protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :creditos, :role, :birthday, :dni, :address, :phone, :gender])
  end

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  def configure_account_update_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :creditos, :role, :birthday, :dni, :address, :phone, :gender])
  end

  # The path used after sign up.
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource) #Resource is the user just created

    empresa = Empresa.create(user_id: resource.id)
    resource.empresa_id = empresa.id
    if resource.save(validate: false)
      edit_empresa_path(resource.empresa)
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Ha habido un problema"
      redirect_to (root_path)
    end
  end

  # The path used after sign up for inactive accounts.
  # def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  #   super(resource)
  # end

  private

  def authorize_admin!
    unless user_signed_in? && current_user.admin?
      redirect_to root_path, alert: "Tú no eres administrador."
    end
  end

end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  private
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |user|
      user.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :role, :creditos )
    end
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update) do |user|
      user.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, :role, :creditos )
    end
  end
end
```

Note: I have verified several times with different accounts that the current password is ok. The methods above were used one at a time. Not simultaneously.

[image]

Comment: Why do you need an email there?
If the user can change password he is already signed in.
As I see you have custom registration controller. It would be helpful if you show the full code of it?

Comment: Here It is. However, this controller was also generated by Devise, making only a little tweak for my app purpose.